# Mouseover links display in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, view, mouseover

I would like to know whether there are any **Drupal (6.x) modules and/or theming tutorials** that can implement the effect of hiding and showing certain (clickable) elements of a view listing only when on mouse hover within the item's div (and not as a tool tip or popup). e.g. in [http://rusoom.com/](http://rusoom.com) the **Author, Like, Info** and *Share* links of each image (view item) only show on mouse over.

Another example will be the display of **Favorite, Retweet** and **Reply** displayed on each tweet on mouse-hover, when logged in to Twitter (http://twitter.com) and viewing any tweet stream.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) function in jQuery and create my custom JavaScript code (in a custom module or in the theme). Here is an example of the code:

**file: sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/template.php**

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');
}
?>
```

**file: sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/mytheme.js**

```
$('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $('.hidden').show();
})
```

**HTML** (Views generated code)

```
<div class="box">Mouse over me to see hidden content</div>
<div class="hidden" style="display:none">This is hidden</div>
```

This is a quick mockup but it should get you in the right direction. If there isn't a module for this you can consider making one from this code!
Good luck

Comment: Thanks Naoise. I'll definitely try it out and give you feedback.

Comment: Tried a basic example and it worked, but it seems my Javascript has be enclosed in `code`$(document).ready(function () {

Comment: Pardon the previous incomplete comment. I tried a basic example and it worked fine, but it seems my JavaScript functions have to be enclosed in `$(document).ready(function () { //functions_here });`. Though a trivial question, why does it not work without the 'ready' function? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Normally you reference elements of the DOM with your javascript. If the DOM is not `ready` then those elements can't be accessed.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot Naoise. That has really give me good grounds for adding more effects to my views.